# Can someone help fix Conway's Game of Life

Tags: python, function

I am using Python 3.6. I have had a quick look on google, and on stack overflow, but I am yet to see one with my problem. The problem is that my function that should find the number of live neighbours, is returning the wrong value (but only sometimes).

This is the code:

```
def neighbourCount(i, j):
    neighbours = 0

    try:
        if grid[i-1][j-1] == "1":
            neighbours += 1
    except:
        pass

    try:
        if grid[i-1][j] == "1":
            neighbours += 1
    except:
        pass

    try:
        if grid[i-1][j+1] == "1":
            neighbours +=1
    except:
        pass

    try:
        if grid[i][j-1] == "1":
            neighbours += 1
    except:
        pass

    try:
        if grid[i][j+1] == "1":
            neighbours += 1
    except:
        pass

    try:
        if grid[i+1][j-1] == "1":
            neighbours += 1
    except:
        pass

    try:
        if grid[i+1][j] == "1":
            neighbours += 1
    except:
        pass

    try:
        if grid[i+1][j+1] == "1":
            neighbours +=1
    except:
        pass

    return(neighbours)



grid = [
    ["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"],
    ["0","0","1","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"],
    ["0","0","1","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"],
    ["0","0","1","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"],
    ["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"],
    ["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"],
    ["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"],
    ["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"],
    ["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"],
    ["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"]
    ]

newGrid = [
    ["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"],
    ["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"],
    ["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"],
    ["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"],
    ["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"],
    ["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"],
    ["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"],
    ["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"],
    ["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"],
    ["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"]
    ]


game = 1
while game == 1:

    for i in range(0,10):
        print(*grid[i], sep='  ')

    numNeigh = []

    for i in range(0,10):
        row = []
        for j in range(0,10):
            neighbours = neighbourCount(i, j)
            if grid[i][j] == "1" and ( neighbours>1 and neighbours<4 ):
                newGrid[i][j] = "1"
            if grid[i][j] == "1" and ( neighbours<2 or neighbours>3 ):
                newGrid[i][j] = "0"
            if grid[i][j] == "0" and neighbours == 3:
                newGrid[i][j] = "1"
            row.append(neighbours)

        numNeigh.append(row)

    for i in numNeigh:
        print(i)
    for i in newGrid:
        print(i)

    print("\n\n")

    grid = newGrid

    input()
```

This is the output (first chunk: grid array)(second chunk: neighbours that each cell has)(third chunk: newGrid array):

```
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 2, 4, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
```

(Note for above: I also have a 2D array for "newGrid" that is the same as "grid" but with only "0")

The middle chunk shows the amount of neighbours each position has, but rather than showing "1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0...." on the third row down, it is showing "1,2,4,2,2,0,0..."

Comment: Please provide an easily usable input array. So show how you create `grid`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I have made an edit showing the definition of "grid".

Answer (score 0):

Your issue probably lies in the line where you create `newGrid`. Unless you properly create a copy of `grid` (deep copy), then the elements will be pointing to the same lists (shallow copy). So when you change `newGrid`, `grid` is being altered as well. To properly create a copy of grid, change your `newGrid` line from:

```
newGrid = grid.copy()
```

to:

```
newGrid = [x[:] for x in grid]
```

---

Note: Using numpy would automatically create appropriate deep copies on calls to numpy array's `copy` method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't think this will work. 
During the "for i in range(1,10):" and "for j in range(1,10):" lines, all items within "newGrid" are being redefined, so the assigning doesn't really make a difference. The only reason that I laid it out in the same way was to make sure all of the indices would line up.
I did, however, try using this line instead of defining "newGrid" the same way as "grid", but I had the same result as before.

Comment: @Ben I don't think you used it properly then. Show the code you tried to enter instead.

Comment: I have updated the post; it now shows the whole code.

Comment: @Ben I ran your code and not only is the input `grid` different, it also gives the correct output (not what you show here)..

Comment: can I ask which version of Python you use?
I use IDLE Python 3.6.2.

Comment: @Ben Python 3.6.2 in terminal

Comment: is it possible that there are inconsistencies between versions?